# What date does a 1738 British author intend by "soon after the revolution"?

Tags: britain

In the February 1738 [The Gentleman's Magazine, Volume XIII](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZExGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA80&dq=mary%20reign%20play%20tag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXtsO8vqbcAhXQxFkKHaanCF8Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=mary%20reign%20play%20tag&f=false) at page 80:

It is stated:

> A manuscript writen by a *great Uncle* of mine, who dy'd soon after the *Revolution* came lately into my hands.

What does "soon after the Revolution" mean?

The [Wikipedia page for English Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Revolution) makes it sound like there is more than one possibility.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I think 1688 is correct, because the other possibilities that Wikipedia gives are treated as Marxist theories, and 1738 is before Marx.  But I wanted an answer from HistorySE that I could quote for this SkepticsSE question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41763/is-tag-named-for-touch-and-go

Comment: The requests for it perhaps could have been phrased nicer (hint everyone), so a double thank you goes to you for adding the clarification to the question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In the text, he describes the history of the game of Blind Man's Buff and other childrens' games through various reigns. At the bottom-right of the page, the text states:

> "At the Revolution, when all People recover'd their Liberty, ..."

Since this immediately follows a paragraph describing how the game was played during the reigns of Charles II and James II, it is clear that "the Revolution" referred to here is The [Glorious Revolution of 1688](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution).